# RxKotlin COUNT with GROUP BY and return a list

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I have a list of recurring elements in Kotlin, say:

```
val result = arrayListOf<String>("AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB")
```

I would like to group them by their value along with how many times they appear, so the output would be pairs of:

```
{"AA", 2}, {"BB", 2}, {"CC", 1}
```

I have resolved the problem using in Kotlin as follows:

```
val ans = result.map { it.value }
            .groupBy { it }
            .map { Pair(it.key, it.value.size) }
            .sortedByDescending { it.second }
```

I want to write same code in RxKotlin for learning and tried with the following but do not know how to apply `map`/`flatMap` to achieve the result.

```
val source = Observable.fromIterable(result)
source.groupBy{ it }.subscribe { showresult(it) }
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at how to [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I have edited it for you now, but just something to keep in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```kotlin
source.groupBy { it }
.flatMapSingle { g -> g.count().map { Pair(g.getKey(), it) } }
.toSortedList { a, b -> b.second.compareTo(a.second) }
.subscribe { list -> println(list) }
```

Comment: thanks.  I have solved before your answer however this is correct answer.